# JUNG2 - how to scale - make all vertexes visible

Tags: java, jung

I want to write method to autoscale/center the graph. I want to make all vertices visible, even these with large XY coordinates. I'm working with StaticLayout. I was trying to use 
In other words - i want to display particular piece of cartesian space (ie: 1000x1000) in VisualizationViewer with resolution 500x500.
 Do you have solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution for this. Anyway, I had a similar problem and I fixed it by writing this function:

```
    private void scaleToRightAmount(VisualizationViewer<ModelObject, ModelEdge> vv) {

    Point2D ivtfrom = vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().inverseTransform(Layer.VIEW, new Point2D.Double(vv.getWidth(),vv.getHeight()));
    MutableTransformer modelTransformer = vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().getTransformer(Layer.LAYOUT);
    modelTransformer.scale(0.9, 0.9, ivtfrom);
    vv.repaint();
}
```